# flutter how to draw the map direction between multiple places in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

Im building one application in which contains google maps. Im able to draw the draw the direction between two cities, but problem is i'll receive list of cities from server then i need the direction betweeen those cities(might be more than 5+ cities).

I had researched a lot from internet, but i could not find the solution to implement the direction between the multiple cities.

Can any one help me, how to achieve  like below?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Distance Matrix API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix

Comment: distance matrix will be different one right ?

Comment: Distance Matrix can help you show directions for either multiple origins and destinations.